# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar una Lista simples enlazadas?

Tags: java

Quisiera saber cómo podría ordenar mi lista simple enlazada cuyos elementos son solo números, quisiera poner una opción que me ordene todos los elementos de mi lista.

[image: Opciones de mi menú]

Las clases con las que trabajo

[image: Clases]

Mi clase Nodo

```
public class Nodo {
    public int dato;
    public Nodo sig;

    public Nodo(int d){
        this.dato=d;
        this.sig=null;
    }
    public Nodo(int d, Nodo n){
        dato=d;
        sig=n;
    }

    public void Enlace(Nodo g)
    {
        sig = g;
    }
}
```

Mi clase Lista

```
public class LISTA {

protected Nodo inicio, fin;
protected Nodo pFound;

public LISTA() {
    inicio = null;
    fin = null;
}

public void AgregInicio(int elem) {
    inicio = new Nodo(elem, inicio);
    if (fin == null) {
        fin = inicio;
    }
}

public void MostrarLista() {
    Nodo recorrer = inicio;
    System.out.println();
    while (recorrer != null) {
        System.out.print("[" + recorrer.dato + "]--->");
        recorrer = recorrer.sig;
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes realizar dicho trabajo en base al algoritmo insertion sort.

Comment: En [esta](http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/) web hay varios algoritmos de ordenación que puedes utilizar para ordenar tu lista

Comment: Usa las listas propias de java y sus métodos para ordenarlas. Si esto no te sirve porque lo que quieres es aprender a implementar métodos de ordenación, entonces no le veo sentido a la pregunta. ¿Cómo vas a aprender si te dan el código?

Comment: No se entiende por qué estás implementando tu propia lista enlazada (y qué relación hay entre eso y el código que muestras en la imagen). Por qué no usas un simple LinkedList or ArrayList ?

Comment: `LISTA` no es un buen nombre de una clase, cambiala por `Lista` mismo caso para `ENLAZADA` Es buena practica ir programando junto a los estandares del lenguaje

Comment: Todo lo que necesitas para resolverlo esta aquí: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_ordenamiento

Comment: @jasilva, desgraciadamente algunos tutoriales o ejemplos en español son escritos en mayusculas, yo tuve el mismo problema hasta que empece a trabajar y me di cuenta de esta mala costumbre.

Comment: @leonbloy ejercicios de clases, me imagino

Answer (score 2):

Creo te seria mas eficiente que usar una burbuja mejorada, para evitar ciclos innecesarios.

El punto clave es no es solo cambiar los punteros para moverse a través de la lista, sino cambiar las ligas entre los diferentes nodos e identificar el nodo  anterior.

Suponiendo que esta es mi clase LinkedList.

```
public class LinkedList {

Materia first, last;
int length;

static LinkedList ll;
```

Y este es el método, notese que tenemos dos escenarios para el intercambio de los nodos y el almacenamiento del nodo anterior. Aqui lo ordeno en base al atributo nombre.

```
 public void bubbleSort() {
    if (length > 1) {
        boolean cambio;
        do {
            Materia actual = first;
            Materia anterior = null;
            Materia siguiente = first.siguiente;
            cambio = false;
            while ( siguiente != null ) {
                if (actual.getNombre().compareTo(siguiente.getNombre())>0) {
                    cambio = true;
                    if ( anterior != null ) {
                        Materia sig = siguiente.siguiente;
                        anterior.siguiente = siguiente;
                        siguiente.siguiente = actual;
                        actual.siguiente = sig;
                    } else {
                        Materia sig = siguiente.siguiente;
                        first = siguiente;
                        siguiente.siguiente = actual;
                        actual.siguiente = sig;
                    }
                    anterior = siguiente;
                    siguiente = actual.siguiente;
                } else { 
                    anterior = actual;
                    actual = siguiente;
                    siguiente = siguiente.siguiente;
                }
            } 
        } while( cambio );
    }
}
```

Espero resulte de utilidad.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Mover datos de LLS GIF][1]

**Usando esta imagen que posteo @Federico, la imagen explica muy bien lo que se debe hacer esta genial!.**

> Les dejo el código que yo implemente en mi LLS:

```
public void ordenar()
{
            int t=1,c=1;
            Nodo act = nodo_inicial;/*definimos que el apuntador act esta en el primer nodo*/
            while(act.ap_sig !=null)//Este while cuenta el total de nodos.
            {
                act = act.ap_sig;
                c++;
            }
            /* estas 2 variebles solo son variables que guardaran el valor temporalmente*/
            int tem=0;
            String tem1 ="";
            //aqui se hace el ordenamiento
            do{
                act = nodo_inicial;//aux esta en el primer nodo
                Nodo sig = act.ap_sig;//esta en el siguiente nodo 
                while(act.ap_sig != null)
                {
                    if(act.dato > sig.dato)
                    {
                        tem = act.dato;
                        tem1 = act.palabra;
                        act.dato = sig.dato;
                        act.palabra = sig.palabra;
                        sig.dato = tem;
                        sig.palabra = tem1;
                        //imprimir();
                        act = act.ap_sig;
                        sig = sig.ap_sig;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //[1] [3] [2]
                        //    act sig 
                        act = act.ap_sig;
                        sig = sig.ap_sig;
                        //imprimir();
                    }
                }
                t++;
            }while(t<=c);//act.ap_sig != null);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

En tu caso, que intentas ordenar tu clase **LISTA (LinkedList)** por **número (dato que almacena cada objeto LISTA, aparte de la referencia al siguiente Nodo)**, lo más recomendable desde mi punto de vista y como te ha dejado en un comentario *@Luigi Mendoza* es utilizar el algoritmo de inserción.

**Algoritmo de Inserción** *(OJO, es el ejemplo 'genérico' típico)*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void insertSort(int[] array)  {
        int i, temp, j;
        for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            temp = array[i];
            j = i - 1;
            while ( (array[j] > temp) && (j >= 0) ) {
                array[j + 1] = array[j];
                j--;
            }
            array[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
```

> En tu caso, podrías pasar como parámetro siempre el **Nodo de
>   inicio**, y a partir de él, aplicar la sustitución según el **número
>   (dato Nodo)** e ir cambiando entonces cada Nodo que recorres a partir
>   del de inicio su referencia al siguiente y al anterior (sería modificar tu LISTA 'simple enlazada' a una 'doblemente enlazada'.

[Enlace a InsertionSort - Fuente Wikipedia (inglés)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

Comment: están bien chidas tus imágenes pero son en un arreglo, no en una lista enlazada uno a uno.

Answer (score -3):

Hay varios tipos de sorting, uno de los más efectivos para tu caso creo que sería el BubbleSort.

La idea es ir dejando los números mayores al final de la lista y es muy fácil de implementar.
Te dejo una imágen explicativa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entendi por qué el voto negativo

Comment: me parece que podrías dar un ejemplo un poco más elaborado (no sólo un GIF). Por otra parte, BubbleSort es conocido por ser bastante ineficiente

Comment: Bueno, la idea está, solo falta implementarlo =)

Comment: Me pareció importante dejarle la parte de codificación a él, ya que es la parte interesante del código, pensar como llevar a cabo el sort. 

Sobre lo otro que dices, se que bubbleSort no es la forma más eficiente de ordenar una lista, pero me pareció un buen método para insertarse en el mundo del sorting, es de los más sencillos de implementar

Comment: Apoyo tu idea @Federico pero creo que deberías explicar por lo menos el algoritmo a utilizar. Recuerda que es una lista enlazada, no un arreglo.

Comment: creo que le faltó justificación de por qué sería uno de los más efectivos. El gif está mega genial, pero es en un arreglo, no en una lista enlazada uno a uno